# Python: can't get a subset for variables with for loop

Tags: python, variables, iteration

I'm kind of new to Python, and I'd like to ask a question about for loops and variable subset. It turns out that I'm working with high dimensional data from oficial polls. Then, I have a panel data which accounts for five years, and in which variables from different years can be identified by the last two digits. For example: "codpeople_16" belongs to 2016 year. In order to work with observations at different times, I need to get a list for all variables that account for one year: lets say, for instance, variables for 2016.

Then, I have a list of all variables in my dataframe. It looks like this:

```
names = (a200_16, a201_16, a202_16..., a200_17, a201_17, a202_17..., a200_18...)
```

Then I have defined a function as follows:

```
def itercolumn(names):
  result = ""
  final = []
  for i in names:
    result = i[-2:]
    if result == "16":
      print(i)
```

It works and prints all variables from the year 2016. However, I need to have a list of all variables of 2016. Then, I need a function to return. I've tried this:

```
ddef itercolumn(names):
  result = ""
  final = []
  for i in names:
    result = i[-2:]
    if result == "16":
      final += i
      return final
```

It returns only the first iteration characters, but I need all variables that meet the condition. Then, what could I do to get a list for all variables that meet the condition?

Regards

Comment: `final += i` should be `final.append(i)`

Comment: or `final += i,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `return` with `yield`.

```
def itercolumn(names):
  for i in names:
    result = i[-2:]
    if result == "16":
      yield i

print(list(itercolumn(names)))
```

or

```
def itercolumn(names):
  final = []
  for i in names:
    result = i[-2:]
    if result == "16":
      final.append(i)
  return final

print(itercolumn(names))
```

or you can use list comprehension

```
result = [name for name in names if name[-2:] == '16']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def itercolumn(names)
  result = "":
  final = []
  for i in names:
    result = i[-2:]
    if result == "16":
      final.append(i)
  return final
```

Change your code to this.

Comment: After you do that, you can return final